# Problem showing the probability of a sequence of sets converges to 1.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Im reading notes on M-estimators and the following Theorem is presented:

> **Theorem: Assuming [...], the local M-estimator $\hat{\psi}_n$ will be well defined with probability converging to 1.**
>   *Proof:*
>   For every $\epsilon>0$ we have previously shown the existence of a sequence $(F_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of measurable sets and a constant $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $P(F_n)> 1 - \epsilon$ for $n\geq n_0$. Furthermore we have shown that if $\omega \in F_n$ then $\hat{\psi}_n(\omega)$ is well-defined.

I understand the each single statements in the proof, but i don't see how (assuming this is what is meant by "well-defined with probability converging to 1") i construct a sequence of sets $(G_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ if $G_n$ has occurred then $\hat{\psi}_n$ is well-defined, and with the property 
$$
P(G_n) \to_n 1
$$

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For anyone who might stumble upon this post: The construction turned out to be quite easy. This is at least one way to show that $\hat{\psi}_n$ is asymptotically well-defined.**

For each $\delta >0 $ there exists $n_\delta \in\mathbb{N}$ and a sequence of events $(F^\delta_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{F}$ such that $P(F^\delta_n)>1-\delta$ for $n\geq n_\delta$ and if any $F^\delta_n$ for $\delta\in (0,1)$ has occurred $\hat{\psi}_n$ is well defined.

Now define
$$
G_n := \bigcup_{\delta\in (0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}} F_n^\delta  \in \mathcal{F}, \quad \quad \text{ for } n\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
We see that if $\omega\in G_n$ then $\hat{\psi}_n(\omega)$ is well-defined. Furthermore we see for any $\delta \in (0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$ that
$$
1\geq   \limsup_{n\to\infty}P(G_n) \geq \liminf_{n\to\infty}P(G_n) \geq \liminf_{n\to\infty} P(F^\delta_n) \geq 1-\delta
$$
Since this holds for any rational $\delta \in (0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$ we conclude that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(G_n)=1 $$  This shows that $\hat{\psi}_n$ is well-defined with probability converging to 1 for $n$ tending to infinity